# How to not show label, when token value is empty?

Tags: civievent, tokens

I have a set of tokens that sometimes has values in them, and sometimes not.

How can I send an email where labels only are visible when value is filled?

Example:
I want to send an event registration confirmation letter. In the event signup form, I have several custom fields, that are stored in in the particiapant record.

**Example**:

*Your info;
Number of rooms: «tokenvalue.customfield1»*

**Example when token value is filled:**

*Your info;
Number of rooms: 2*

**Desired behaviour when token value is not filled:**

*Your info;*

**Current behaviour when value is not filled:**

*Your info; Number of rooms:*

Any tip or pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the event confirmation template you'll see some sections with constructs like this:

```
{assign var="greeting" value="{contact.email_greeting}"}{if $greeting}<p>{$greeting},</p>{/if}
```

You can edit the template and include something similar for your tokens.